# what's the meaning of "Closing the Circle"

Tags: meaning

I saw this title at the end of an article (I'd guess meaning *conclusion*?)

What is the meaning of *Closing the Circle*? Does in mean, *in conclusion*?

Comment: Without context it's near impossible to guess a meaning. Maybe you are drawing a circle, and the last bit of that, when you connect to the beginning, you can call "closing the circle".

Comment: it's a title at the end of an article, i guess its meaning: conclusion

Comment: Yes, conclusion, or actually, "to come back at the beginning". There is a difference in meaning. Normally a conclusion would be a "round up", but you don't have to return to the beginning (of your idea, of your story, of your article. Closing the circle _does_ indicate that.

Comment: @Behzad Please don't add relevant information in comments. [***Edit your question***](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/150983/edit) to include it there.

Comment: to go full circle?

Comment: There are several different meanings, dependent on context.  You gave us no context.

Answer (score 1):

I taught my son to fish, and my son taught my grandson to fish.
My grandson caught a fish and gave it to me. In doing so he closed the circle!

A pumpkin vine grew out of my compost pile and produced an unexpected crop of pumpkins. After preparing the pumpkins to cook I put the scraps in the compost pile, in doing so I closed the circle!

I received a telephone call last week from a young boy asking to speak to my young daughter. Today I worked at the school canteen with a lady who introduced herself as the mother of the young boy. In doing so she closed the circle.

Closing the loop is often used in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

While you didn't provide context on your question, I will try to give you my take on this.

That could mean the act of rounding up a point. For example, you made several arguments about, say, the constitutionality of a law. At the end of your discourse, you may want to "close the circle" by giving a closing remark. To close a circle, then, could mean to cap off.

Answer (score -2):

Those answers are all great, but there is another definition promoted by a book called "The Circle."  Notice the Google logo is 3/4 or a circle.  Per the book, closing the circle means Google obtaining all the personal information about everyone on earth and monitoring everyone too.  It reality, they aren't too far from it.